# нарисовать елку c#

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста это написать, я только начал изучать шарп, не понимаю что не так.
вот мой код:

```
namespace Exercise021
{
  using System;
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(String[] args)
      {
            PrintRightTriangle(4);
      }

      public static void PrintStars(int number)
    {
          var star = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", number));
          Console.Write(star);
    }

    public static void PrintSpaces(int number)
    {
            var space = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", number));
            Console.Write(space);
    }

    public static void PrintRightTriangle(int size)
        {
            for (int f = 1; f <= size; f++) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
                {
                  PrintStars(i);
                }
                PrintSpaces(f);
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
        }
   }
}
```

задача:

> Section 1 Define a method called PrintSpaces(int number) that produces
> the number of spaces specified by number. The method does not print
> the line break.
>
> You will also have to either copy the PrintStars method from your
> previous answer or reimplement it in this exercise template.
>
> Section 2 Create a method called PrintRightTriangle(int size) that
> uses PrintSpaces and PrintStars to print the correct triangle. So the
> method call PrintRightTriangle(4) should print the following:
>
> ```
> // NOTICE THE AMOUNT OF WHITESPACE    
>    *  
>   **  
>  ***  
> ****
> ```
>
> Note! The comments in this and next examples are not part of the
> print, but only to emphasize the difference to previous work. Section
> 3 Define a method called ChristmasTree(int height) that prints the
> correct Christmas tree. The Christmas tree consists of a triangle with
> the specified height and the base. The base is two stars high and
> three stars wide, and is placed at the center of the triangle's
> bottom. The tree is to be constructed by using the methods PrintSpaces
> and PrintStars.
>
> For example, the call ChristmasTree(4) should work as following:
>
> ```
> // NOTICE THE AMOUNT OF WHITESPACE
>    * 
>   *** 
>  *****
> ******* 
>   *** 
>   ***
> ```
>
> The call ChristmasTree(10) should work like this:
>
> ```
> // NOTICE THE AMOUNT OF WHITESPACE
>          * 
>         *** 
>        ***** 
>       ******* 
>      ********* 
>     *********** 
>    ************* 
>   *************** 
>  ***************** 
> ******************* 
>         *** 
>         ***
> ```
>
> Note! Heights shorter that 3 don't have to work correctly!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и результаты работы в виде скриншотов или ссылок на архивы. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте всю необходимую информацию.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i >= size; i++)` — этот цикл не выполнится ни разу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё намного проще, чем кажется, простая математика. Даже проще, чем в условии написано.

```
static void PrintSpaces(int number)
{
    string spaces = new string(' ', number);
    Console.Write(spaces);
}

static void PrintStars(int number)
{
    string stars = new string('*', number);
    Console.WriteLine(stars);
}

static void ChristmasTree(int height)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int offset = height - i - 1;
        PrintSpaces(offset);
        int width = i * 2 + 1;
        PrintStars(width);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        PrintSpaces(height - 2);
        PrintStars(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: большое вам спасибо!!!!

Answer (score -1):

На Си ёлка выглядит примерно вот так...

Где `repn` - вывести в консоль символ `ch`, `c` раз.

А `nl` - вывести знак новой строки.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void repn(int c, char ch) {
    char *cc = (char*) calloc(c+1, 1);
    memset(cc, ch, c);
    fputs(cc, stdout);
    free(cc);
}

void nl() {
    fputs("\n", stdout);
}

int main() {
    int sp = 8,
        eg = 1;
    while (sp > 1) {
        repn(sp, ' ');
        repn(eg, '#');
        nl();
        sp -= 1;
        eg += 2;
    }
    repn(7, ' '); repn(3, '#'); nl();
    repn(7, ' '); repn(3, '#'); nl();
}
```